# How to return a custom HTTP code in a Restler request?

Tags: php, restler

I would like to return code `201 Created` in some cases in my API. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered accidentally that adding `@status «code»` to the method documentation alters the success response code, as follows:

```php
/**
 * Creates a post.
 * @status 201
 *
 * @param string $title {@from body} Post title
 * @param string $message {@from body} Post body
 */
protected function post($title, $message) {
    return Posts::create(compact('title', 'message'));
}
```

Comment: ...You mean that they *double-parse* files for the heredoc comments? One more framework on blacklist due to being not opcacheable.

Comment: Could you add more information about "not being opcacheable"?

Comment: And yes, they do that. If you read the documentation you'll notice they take information about where some arguments are presented (url or body) from documentation as well (the `@from`). It's also used for rate-limiting and optionally for access protection (what can be done using protected methods directly as well).

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, could you add more information on "not being opcacheable"?

Comment: an opcache (such as zend or APC) pre-caches a pre-parsed PHP script so that the parsing is done only once. This is a method to gain in processing speed. By forcing a double-parse, you're deliberately forsaking this. More info at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php .

Comment: oh, duh! got it now!
I had understood first that parsing the PHP code would disable opcache. Instead you meant that opcache still works, but as you're manually parsing it, you make it slower anyway.
Maybe Restler maintains some sort of cache about the methods? Let's hope so (:

Comment: As you can read from the [quick start guide](http://restler3.luracast.com/#7--start-production) You should use production mode to reap the benefits of opcache and more

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** - As I have been informed not the correct way to do it for restler but in general with php for custom status messages this is what you would do:

User [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header("HTTP/1.0 201 Created");
```

Comment: Whilst this would be good for generic PHP, Restler will overwrite it with a 200 if you allow it to.

Comment: not familiar with the product... will have to dig deeper... thanks

Comment: if you issue a `header()` call for a certain field, and PHP receives another `header()` for the same value, PHP will silently drop the first. Typical example: `?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header("Content-type: text/html");
header("Content-type: image/png");` ... outputs image/png.

Comment: If you're going to use Restler, what is the point of doing that?

Comment: (Not just that, but that also prevents any Restler clean-up/rate-throttling updates that are not in `__destruct` from running. That's horrible practice.)

Comment: conceded... just seems hacky to go down a prescribed error code path to signify a success. +1 for keeping me honest.

Comment: Tell that to whoever invented Restler? I don't like it either. However, it is less hackish than `die()`, as an exception will not, unless uncaught, break anything.

Comment: I would also add here that, be `header` the right PHP way to do that, the question is solely about Restler. Thus, this answer is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not deleting because I can image enough people familiar with the standard way of doing this and new to using restler sharing my misconception.